# How to run a WAR on Tomcat if the project isn't considered as a web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I would be glad if you could help me with this. 
At my new job, I've been asked to implement some improvements to a program deployed on web. This program was developed in a PC with the following:

Java 1.6.29
Tomcat 6.0
Eclipse Ganimede

I've checked the source code which is in the machine, and even if the project was built on a web environment, the code can't be found as a web project on Eclipse, it appears as a common project.

In this moment, they are asking me to run the project in the machine in order to run some tests.

As it isn't a web project, I tried to run the program using the option "Run as" in Eclipse over Tomcat, but it indicates that it isn't a web project and hence, cannot deploy it.

My solution was to build a compressed WAR and to copy this file to the webapp folder from Tomcat, I then execute Tomcat and this generates the project folder, problem is, the route of the project (http://localhost:8080/MyApplication) shows an Error 404.

My question then is: What can I do to run the project on Tomcat?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's a practice to manually transfer modified files to the deployed location and simply remote debug from Eclipse to see if it's running.

Comment: Hey @Pumpkin, could you also share the list of files in the project root folder? It is possible that the project is being managed by a build tool - possibly - maven, gradle or sbt. Also, check if there is an .iml file (idea project).

Answer (score 0):

first of all confirm if the project requires an container to run it.
If its a web project consisting of jsp/html/JSF components, tomcat by default considers index.xxx page to be the default first page. If there is no file by this name in your project you will receive the resource not found error.
(xxx being the place holder for appropriate extension).

Best solution would be to create a new web project in eclipse and importing the components of the existing project, to ensure the environment is correctly set up for the web project.